# How to insert into a column in data grid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

```xml
<DataGrid Width="300" Height="200" Name="datagrid">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="artists" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="albums" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

In cs file i have:

```
string artist_s = "something";
```

I want to insert artist_s string into artists column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataGrids don't take values for specific columns, you have items, one item represents one row. Please see [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) for more information and some examples.

You could add an entry which just does not set all properties though, e.g.

```xml
<DataGrid Name="testGrid">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}"/> <!-- Those bindings are needed to display the data -->
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Occupation}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

```
testGrid.Items.Add(new { Name = "John" });
testGrid.Items.Add(new { Occupation = "Programmer" });
testGrid.Items.Add(new { Name = "Skeet", Occupation = "Übermensch" });
```

Which produces:

[image: Screenshot]

As you can see each item has its own row.

---

If you do not know how bindings work, read [this article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx).

Comment: Thx for the explanation. So are Datagrids than suitable for storing a collection of data or should i use something else in wpf ?

Comment: I suggest you use two `ListBoxes` instead if the two collections are disconnected.

Comment: I was thinking also to write the stuff inside a database later which i already know, but i didn't know what to use or how to use it because i am new to wpf and this kind stuff. Thank you and thx for the Microsoft link.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<DataGrid Width="300" Height="200" Name="datagrid">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="artists" Binding="{Binding artist_s}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="albums" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

This is assuming you have your data context defined already.

Comment: When i run this nothing happens. I don't know what you mean by: This is assuming you have your data context defined already. I want to insert a simple string into a column. This is all i have.